Why is subtracting pandas.timedelta from pandas.date not vectorized?
Running this on Pandas 2.2 and I see a PerformanceWarning only when subtracting timedelta from date but not subtracting timedelta from datetime:
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2015, 2016], "month": [2, 3], "day": [4, 5]})
s1 = pd.to_datetime(s1)


df = pd.DataFrame(s1)
df = df.rename(columns={0: "t1", 1: "t2"})
df["day"] = df["t1"].dt.date
df["n"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["t1"].dt.day_of_week)

# Throws a not vectorized warning
df["week"] = df["day"] - df["n"]

# No warnings is it actually vectorized?
df["week2"] = df["t1"] - df["n"]
df["week2"] = df["week2"].dt.date

print(df[["week", "week2"]])

Am I missing something?
Do I have to convert all pd.date columns to pd.datetime when I want to subtract or add a timedelta to ensure it's vectorized?
I expect both operations for column "week" and "week2" to be vectorized.

TL;DR: Just use a datetime with hours etc. set to zero to represent a date. pandas only has a built-in datetime type, no separate time and date.

Short answers:
Am I missing something? yes, the "time" and "timezone" parts.
Do I have to convert all pd.date columns to pd.datetime when I want to subtract or add a timedelta to ensure it's vectorized? yes, you have to convert to datetime type (you can directly use the original one you have on df["t1"]).
Long answer:
If you execute a dt.date you will actually get an array of python datetime.date objects (with just the date part of Timestamps without time and timezone information) (as described on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html). So, as it is just one part of the datetime it is recognized as one pandas object dtype, and the vectorized operation is not able to recognize it as an entire datetime value so it throws the warning (even it can bring wrong values in the difference because it doesn't consider the "time" and "timezone").
On the other hand, your df["t1"] is a pandas datetime object and your df["n"] is a pandas timedelta object, so, you can do the vectorized operation without warning.
